# List vs VStack (in ScrollView)

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I prefer using `VStack + ScrollView` to create a more complex newsfeed-like UI.

For instance, I can customize dividers and get rid of the disclosure indicator that comes with `NavigationLink` in `List`.

But performance wise, is there any difference between the two?

**Is it correct to assume that `List` is meant for a simple list UI and `VStack` for a more complex UI, just like how TableView and CollectionView used to be?**

Comment: In short, no. `List` is like (or if prefer, based on) `UITableView`, so reused cells, etc. But `ScrollView` is just scrolling view - it holds/constructs all content, and must have some initial content.

Answer (score 3):

List is probably implemented by a TableView, it's dynamic. Currently, ScrollView + VStack is not dynamic, but ScrollView + LazyVStack is.

In the future, ScrollView + LazyVStack might be a better choice.